# python: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'open' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def read_lines():
    readFileName = "readfile.txt"
    f = open(readFileName, 'r+')
    contents = f.read()
        ... # and so on 

read_lines()
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
f = open(readFileName, 'r+')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'open' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This means that further down in your function you create a variable called `open`:

```
open = ...
```

Rename it so that it doesn't clash with the built-in function.

Comment: "somewhere in your function" here means somewhere after your call to `open`.